# How are small triacs able to "switch" or control high power AC loads

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am currently looking ways to control or siwtch a max 220v 35A load. Simple magnetic relay rated for such load would work, but i am exploring the other alternatives too.

here i stumbled into triacs, in which solid state relays are made of. I stumbled into this ic

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/t16t.pdf

and i could not get the grasp on how a small triac such as this one.

is able to switch a high load of 220v 16amps

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

35A needs a heavy duty contactor. It's a relay but designed for switching the high current.

A triac latches on until the current drops to 0. This means that the actual switching off happens at the zero crossing point. Switching on is still done whenever the gate voltage exceeds the turn on threshold. This can result in a inrush current spike but as long as that isn't sustained the triac will be able to deal with it. The one you linked can handle 120A for one cycle.

While the triac is off the isolation is enough to stop current flow.